# creating dict from column with header as key, no list formatting

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

One example of a simple DataFrame

```
  ID1 ID2
0  1   2
1  2   2
```

I need to transform column ID1 into a dict where 'ID1' is the key and the row values are the pure values. My designated output is

```
dict1 = {ID1 : ('1','1'...)}
```

So far i've uses a simple `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict(list)` statement to get the following

```
dict2 = {ID1 : ['1','1'...]}
```

However, dict2 is not working when I pass the dict into my database.
Any suggestions how to create a dict without the squared brackets as in a list, so i get a result as shown in dict1?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this

```
d = {k:tuple(v) for k,v in dict2.items()}
```

Comment: Yes. when k=ID1 and v=('1', '1') and then into dict items with paranthesis instead of squared brackets...

Comment: Worked when temp = tuple(df.ID1.unique()) and then add this into the dict through: dict = {ID1 : temp }

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
df.to_dict()
```

in your small example generated this:

```
{'ID1': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'ID2': {0: 2, 1: 2}}
```

for a single column:

```
df[['ID2']].to_dict()
{'ID2': {0: 2, 1: 2}}
```

Comment: Yeah! however then the problem is the row labels are included in the dict. I'm only concerned in the values from the column and the column header as a key.. only way to do this is through to_dict(list), but it's the wrong format for me, unfortunately..

Comment: This : df[['ID2']].to_dict('list') results in this: {'ID2': [2, 2]} isn't this what you want?